# Format of Linux device name (in /dev)

Tags: linux

Is there a format of names of devices in `/dev`. I know there are conventions like `sd` maps to a disk. I was wondering however if the kernel forces a specific format? I noticed when I tried to attach a device to an arbitrary location like `/dev/helloworld`, it failed (on AWS).

Thanks!

Comment: The failure you mention may have nothing to do with the device name.  The association between the device driver (what you seem to be referring to as the device) and the device node (what you seem to be referring to as the device name) is through the major and minor device numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The initial names of device nodes are set by the respective drivers, but if you know which major/minor numbers a driver uses, you could create other device nodes. (See [here](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/devices.txt;hb=HEAD) for a somewhat incomplete and outdated list.)

For many modern devices, minor numbers are chosen dynamically, so your best bet would be to create a symbolic link to some existing device node, like this:

```
ln -s /dev/tty /dev/helloworld
echo Hi! > /dev/helloworld
```

Your system is likely to have many [udev](http://linux.die.net/man/7/udev) rules to create such symbolic links; look into `/etc/udev/rules.d/` or `/lib/udev/rules.d/`.